# Quadratic regression with upside-down parabola only

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

Currently I'm fitting 2D points with a degree-2 polynomial, using least squares:

$$
b = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T y
$$

Example result:

[image]

My problem is that I would need all parabolas to have a maximum. Meaning: if the resulting polynomial is:

$$
a x^2 + b x + c
$$

then `a < 0`.

Any hints for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing
a unconstrained least-squares fit,
you don't have much control.
In your case,
it looks like your data
is concentrated in a relatively small region,
and it looks like
it tends to be increasing.

Why does the fit
need to have a < 0?

It would help
if your plot
was zoomed in so the
bulk of the data
filled the image.

Comment: Because the samples are always taken from a range that behaves nearly linearly. But I know that at higher ranges the increase would start degrading. (It's not possible to sample those higher ranges.) I'll look up `constrained least squares`, thanks.

Comment: update: I think I'll switch to fitting sigmoid functions. Will read up on it.